# No resource identifier found for the attribute tab gravity in package in xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I am new on Xamarin I created a blank app but it's giving me this error.

No resource identifier found for the attribute  tab gravity in package in xamarin

Answer (score 0):

Check what API version your Android project is targeting against.

You may need to check what SDK you have installed and try to match that.

Comment: i had check by changing API to 18 then 19 but still facing this errot

Comment: Try setting it to 21 and having that sdk installed

Comment: Right click your Android project, select Properties, and provide a screenshot of your application section and your application manifest section to ensure all is correct.

Comment: here is Manifest and other screen shot are below 



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.muneeb.xamarin.testapp">
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
 <application android:label="TestApp"></application>
</mani

Comment: I am not sure if Xamarin Studio is still supported. It is recommended to use Visual Studio for Mac. judging from your screenshot, you should have 25 installed, try that as your target.